# Sending a text from script to a screen

Tags: shell-script, gnu-screen

My whole task sounds like this "Show how many users are working right now, whenever someone has logged out or has logged in, print the new amount of users. Create a new screen and print there text outcome". With the first part I've dealt with it pretty well. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

updateusers(){
    log=$( who | grep "st" | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l);
}

updateusers
temp=$log
echo "Now logged users: $lrn"
while true
do
    updateusers
    if [ $temp -lt $log ]; then
        temp=$log
        echo "User has logged in : $log"
        fi
    if [ $temp -gt $log ]; then
        temp=$log
        echo "User has logged out: $log"
        fi
    sleep 1
done
```

The second task is to create second screen inside the script and print text from this script to it. I've used `screen -S name -p 0 -X stuff "text here/echo command with text"` and `echo text > screen -S name -p 0`. None of that worked for me.

Comment: does `screen /path/to/your-script-name.sh` not work?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to redirect the output of your script (the various `echo` commands) to a temporary file, and then execute a `cat` command inside the screen using that temporary filename as argument.  Something like

```
myreport >foo
screen -S name -X stuff "cat foo"
rm foo
```

(though there are more elegant ways to create a temporary file such as `mktemp`).  As a first step, making your report script a function (or separate file) would allow redirecting its output.